# Followup question on first-order formulas in first-order languages and open formulas.

Tags: logic

This is a followup question to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085455/first-order-formula-in-first-order-language-another-open-language-where-equival). I will reproduce the contents of my original question as follows.

> For any first-order formula $X$ in the first-order language $\langle 0, S, \le\rangle$ (possibly with free variables) does there necessarily exist another open formula $Y$ such that the equivalence $X \equiv Y$ is true on the set of all nonnegative integer numbers?

[Noah Schweber](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/28111/noah-schweber) gives the following answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2085474/389821), which I will reproduce as follows.

> Yes, this is true. The structure $(\mathbb{N}; 0, S, \le)$ admits **quantifier elimination**, and the proof of this is via induction on the complexity of $X$. For an example of such a proof, see [this](http://lara.epfl.ch/w/_media/sav12:qe_presburger_arithmetic.pdf), which goes through the proof of quantifier elimination for a version of Presburger arithmetic.

My new question is, does a similar statement hold for the language $\langle 0, \le\rangle$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, it does not.** The set $\{1\}$ is definable in that structure - it is the set of $x$ such that $$x\not=0\wedge \forall y(y\le x\implies [y=0 \vee y=x]).$$ However, it's not hard to show that it is *not* definable by a quantifier-free formula (there aren't very many sets which are definable by a quantifier-free formula in this structure; see if you can find them all, and prove that your list is exhaustive!). Roughly speaking, the reason is that this language does not have enough *terms*.

Incidentally, note that the successor function *is definable* in this language ($S(x)=y$ iff $x\le y$ and $\neg y\le x$ and $\forall z[x\le z\wedge z\le y\implies x=z\vee z=y]$); combining this with the observation from the previous question that $(\mathbb{N}; 0, \le, S)$ *does* have quantifier elimination, we get two interesting facts:

- Definable expansions of theories without quantifier elimination might "gain" quantifier elimination. (By contrast, it's not hard to show that once you *have* quantifier elimination, you don't lose it by passing to a definable expansion.)
- Since the successor function is definable by a formula with one quantifier, every definable relation on $(\mathbb{N}; 0, \le)$ is definable by a Boolean combination of existential formulas; so, while we don't have full quantifier elimination, the quantifier *hierarchy* does collapse - just not right away.