# Exists first-order formula $Z(x)$ in language $\langle 0, +, \le\rangle$ that over field $\mathbb{Q}$ expresses fact that $x$ is integer?

Tags: logic, model-theory

This is a followup to my previous questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085455/first-order-formula-in-first-order-language-another-open-language-where-equival?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2087230/followup-question-on-first-order-formulas-in-first-order-languages-and-open-form?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Does there exist any first-order formula $Z(x)$ in the language $\langle 0, +, \le\rangle$ that over the field $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers expresses the fact that $x$ is an integer?

I strongly suspect there isn't any, but I don't know how to see that. Could anybody help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct: no such formula exists.

Suppose that $Z(x)$ is such a formula. That is, for each $q \in \mathbb{Q}$
$$\mathfrak{Q} = \langle \mathbb{Q}, 0 , + , \leq \rangle \models Z[q] \Leftrightarrow q \in \mathbb{Z}. \tag{1}$$

Note that the mapping $\sigma (x) = \frac{x}{2}$ is an isomorphism of $\mathfrak{Q}$, and so for each $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ we have that $$\mathfrak{Q} \models Z[q] \Leftrightarrow \mathfrak{Q} \models Z[ \sigma(q) ]. \tag{2}$$
Now consider what happens when $q = 1$: By (2) we have that
$$\mathfrak{Q} \models Z[1] \Leftrightarrow \mathfrak{Q} \models Z[\sigma(1) = \tfrac{1}{2}],$$ which clearly contradicts our assumption (1).

Answer (score 2):

While @komorebi's answer is correct, approaching this question using automorphisms is a bit fragile. In particular, the automorphism method cannot rule out the possibility that the integers are definable *with parameters* (that is, after adding some constants). To see why, observe that there are no non-trivial automorphisms fixing a non-zero number.

Fortunately, there is classification of all definable sets in this structure: a subset of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is definable (possibly with parameters) in the language $(\mathbb{Q},+,<)$ if and only if it is a Boolean combination of solution sets to linear inequalities. In particular, a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ is definable (with parameters) if and only if it is a Boolean combination of intervals and points, so $\mathbb{Z}$ is not definable.

The above result is a consequence of **quantifier elimination** for the theory of **divisible ordered Abelian groups**. (Really, it's just a restatement of that fact.) That fact, in turn, is an approachable exercise: prove by induction on formulas that every formula in the language $(+,<)$ is equivalent (modulo the theory of divisible ordered Abelian groups) to a quantifier free formula.